# Creating addresses from multiple values in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I am trying to create 32 bit addresses in C by combining multiple unsigned int values I have. These multiple values are important and need to be all stored into 1 32 bit address.

For example: Say I have `unsigned int outer = 25`, `unsigned int inner = 984`, `unsigned int offset = 3241`. The outer int has the 10 top bits in the 32 bit address, the inner int has 10 middle bits in the 32 bit address, and the offset has the remaining 12 bits to store its number.

It would look something like:

```
OUTER | INNER | OFFSET
  10      10      12    = 32 bit address
```

I know that, in this example, the outer and inner ints can store values from 0 - 2^10-1 and the offset can store values from 0 - 2^12-1, but with these values I'm not sure how to split them up according to the number of bits that they can have within the 32 bit address then forge/merge everything into the whole address.

Comment: `address = (outer << 22) | (inner << 12) | offset;`

Comment: What do you mean by "split them up according to the number of bits...."?

Comment: I meant that the outer and inner numbers both only have 10 bits each that they are allowed to use within the 32 bit address, and the offset has 12 bits it can use within the 32 bit address. So splitting the up according to the number of bits they are allowed to have within the address and then creating the address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer according to @user3386109:

```
address = (outer << 22) | (inner << 12) | offset;
```

Comment: Per the question, I think that each value needs to be trimmed to the requisite number of bits.  For instance: `address = ((outer & 0x000003ff) << 22) | (inner & 0x000003ff) << 12) | (offset & 0x00000fff);`

Comment: I went ahead and tested this and I get the same answer. I'm not sure if this actually matters but I've already written code to extract the top N bits, mid N bits, and bottom N bits where N is the number of bits I want to extract from the address and it seems to work exactly the same on the regular version as well as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits your goal, but if you allowed you could make a stucture for this like so

```
typedef struct {
  union {
    struct {
      unsigned int offset : 12;
      unsigned int outer : 10;
      unsigned int inner : 10;
    } bits;
    unsigned int address;
  }
} Address;

int main() {
  Address a;

  a.bits.offset = 3241;
  a.bits.inner = 25;
  a.bits.outer = 984;
  printf("outer: %u\ninner: %u\noffset: %u\naddress: %08x", a.bits.outer,
         a.bits.inner, a.bits.offset, a.address);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
outer: 984 
inner: 25     
offset: 3241   
address: 067d8ca9
```

Although this depends on the endiannes and the handling of the bitfields for the particular architecture and compiler.

Comment: Sorry, I would not be allowed to do this. I was testing out @user3386109 and that solution is exactly what I needed, I was about to answer my own question according to his solution

Comment: @WilliamJones Ohh. Okay.

Comment: in C, the actual order of bit fields is implementation defined, so this may not actually produce what you want